# mdl-select label is not visible after drop down value selected

Tags: angular2-mdl

I am using mdl-select in an angular-cli project on a form but cannot seem to get the label to show / float once a drop down value has been selected. The placeholder works fine but only shows whilst no value selected as it should. All other aspects of mdl-select is working perfectly though. Seems like an issue in css but I have not introduced any new css outside of mdl and material related css.

Component HTML

```
<mdl-select label="Country"  floating-label [(ngModel)]="this.currentc">
    <mdl-option  *ngFor="let c of cl" [value]="c">{{c.Description}}</mdl-option>
</mdl-select>
```

Angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [       
    "../node_modules/angular2-mdl/scss/material-design-lite.scss",
    "../node_modules/@angular2-mdl-ext/select/select.scss",
    "../node_modules/@angular2-mdl-ext/popover/popover.scss",
    "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css"        
  ],
```

Comment: can you put your code.

Comment: Any experience with such an issue anyone?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? I'm having that problem, seems turbolinks clashes with the JS in the select